# Session with included header

Tags: php, session, include

I am having trouble getting this if statement to work using the included php file. I know that you have to test if the $_SESSION['name'] is set but for some reason its not letting me use this function in php to test if I set the session for the user.

Here is my Index.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyles.css"/>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Comfortaa:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <?php include 'includes/header.php';?>

        <?php include 'includes/footer.php';?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my updated header.php

```
    <?php
    echo "<header>
    <div class='social'>
    <ul>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='images/Social Media/Facebook.png'/></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='images/Social Media/Twitter-Bird.png'/></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='images/Social Media/Google-Plus.png'/></a></li>
    <li><a href='#'><img src='images/Social Media/Linkedin.png'/></a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    <div class='users'>";

    if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
        echo "
        <ul>
        <li><a href='profile.php'>Profile</a></li>
        <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
        </ul>";
    } else{
        echo "
        <ul>
        <li><a href='signin.php'>Sign-In</a></li>
        <li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>
        </ul>
        </div>";
    }

    echo "</div>
          <h1><a href='index.php'>CollegeConnection</a></h1>
          </header>";
?>
```

Now I am getting this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\xampp\htdocs\CollegeConnection\includes\header.php on line 13

Comment: why are you echoing "if(isset('".$_SESSION['user']."' ?

Comment: this is my included header and the only code i have for the index.php at the moment. But when I try to run it it says that the variable doesnt exist? Should it not be echo'd?

Comment: Forgot a `)` in:  `if(isset($_SESSION['user'])){`

Answer (score 1):

This never will work.

Better way:

```
$content = "<div class='users'>";
if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
    $content .= "<ul>";
    $content .= "<li><a href='profile.php'>Profile</a></li>";
    $content .= "<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>";
    $content .= "</ul>";
} else {
    $content .= "<ul>";
    $content .= "<li><a href='signin.php'>Sign-In</a></li>";
    $content .= "<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>";
    $content .= "</ul>";
}
$content .= "</div>";

echo $content;
```

Comment: Sorry, on "if(isset($_SESSION['user'])" add one more ")":

if(isset($_SESSION['user']))

Comment: Sweet thank you that has been giving me fits all day I was just overlooking the ). Dumb coding mistakes. Hate those haha. Thanks though I gave you the vote

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is probably :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']){
echo "
<ul>
<li><a href='profile.php'>Profile</a></li>
<li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a></li>
</ul>";
} else{
echo "
<ul>
<li><a href='signin.php'>Sign-In</a></li>
<li><a href='register.php'>Register</a></li>
</ul>
</div>";
}
```